# Django: how to use aggregators in this case

Tags: django

I have two tables

```
Parcels
parcel_id       shop        fruit   quantity
1               shop1       apple   10
2               shop1       apple   20
3               shop3       mango   10
4               shop4       banana  10


shop
id      name
1       shop1
2       shop2
3       shop3
4       shop4


fruit
id      name
1       apple
2       mango
3       banana
4       orange
5       grapes


from django.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Parcel(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get the list of quantity of each fruit which are getting parcelled

like

```
Fruit quantities getting parcelled
fruit   quantity
apple   30
mango   20
banana  10
```

What i am doing is

get all the parcels list and get the distinct fruits

then again loop over each fruit and get all the parcels related and calculate the quantity

Is there any way to do this, using annotation and aggregators

Comment: There is no `quantity` field in your `Parcel` model though? Or did you forget to add it to the question?

Comment: added it, forgot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this group by expression

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Parcel.objects.values("fruit__name").annotate(f_quantity=Sum("quantity"))
```

Comment: why should we use values

Comment: This how  we write a *Group By* expression in Django

Comment: do we have to sort also

Comment: can i use this as queryset

Answer (score 0):

Annotate on the model `Fruit` and use the [`Sum` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#sum) function:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum


queryset = Fruit.objects.annotate(quantity=Sum('parcel__quantity')).filter(quantity__gt=0)

for fruit in queryset:
    print(fruit.name, fruit.quantity)
```

Comment: how are using the reverse relation here. I tried this it says ` cannot resolve keyword "parcel__quantity", choices are ...`

Comment: @Santhosh edited try `parcel_set__quantity` instead.

Comment: Also hope this will not showup fruits which are not in the parcel.

Comment: I tried `pracel_set__quantity` it says the same error field not found

Comment: @Santhosh if you don't want fruits whose quantity sums to 0 just add a `.filter(quantity__gt=0)` to filter the results. As for `pracel_set__quantity` that is a typo it is `parcel_set__quantity` (Although I do believe `parcel__quantity` should have worked here did you try it with annotate as you say you had used `values` instead?)

Comment: I tried `parcel_set__quantity` with `annotate` and `values`. it didnt work

Comment: @Santhosh that won't work with `values`, I suggested you to try this: `.annotate(quantity=Sum('parcel__quantity'))`

Answer (score 0):

Simply it can be done as

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Fruit.objects.filter(parcel__isnull=False).annotate(quantity=Sum("parcel__quantity")).values("name", "quantity")
```